# Combining data from different tables in one Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, datagridview

Conditions:

1. List item
2. .net 2.0
3. WinForms
4. Nhibernate

I have 2 classes

```
public class Recipes
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Products Product { get; set; }
    public virtual double Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Products
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I use Nhibernate for load data from database

```
IList<Recipes> recipesList = DbSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Recipes)).List<Recipes>();
IList<Products> productsList = DbSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Products)).List<Products>();
```

How can I combine recipesList and productsList in one Datagridview with possibility of editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Way is create a ViewModel

like

```
public class ProductsRecipes
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }
    public virtual Double ProductCost { get; set; }
    public virtual double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very standard way to do this is just to create another class like:

```
public class dgvRecipeProducts
{
  IList<Recipes> recipesList { get; set; }
  IList<Products> productsList { get; set; }
}
```

and use it as mediator to populate the view and then return it back to the back end where you can manipulate it properly to mirror your DB model.